# Java Mapping Class and List to Generic Types

Tags: java, univocity

I am trying to create a method which accepts a class as parameter and do some operation and return a list of same class.

I am trying to use Generics and have the below code.

**Question:**
What should I do to map the provided class to the BeanListProcessor type and List ?

NOTE: This code is not correct and will produce syntax errors. This is a kind of template to explain my requirement.

```
public static List<?> process(Class<?> bean) {

    List<?> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    BeanListProcessor<bean> processor = new BeanListProcessor<bean>(bean.getClass());

    ....
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Just updated my question to highlight my requirement. Hope this gives clarity.

Comment: Do you want to do anything with that processor? Because right now, you can just `return new ArrayList<?>();`

Comment: Yes. There are some activities that the processor does and return some values. Based on that the values should be returned.

Comment: So it's essentially a `Supplier<List<?>>`?

Comment: @daniu Sorry.. I am not sure what does that mean?

Comment: Author of the library here. Have a look at the `CsvRoutines` class to read stuff into list of objects without a lot of boilerplate. Hope it helps!

Comment: @JeronimoBackes : Using CsvRoutines.parseAll() works fine. But I feel still we need the code marked as answer below. Using CsvRoutines I could not get the headers and other info that I did using the parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to define a generic type at method level - if you want to return *instances* of the type provided as argument in the returned list.

```
public static <T> List<T> process(Class<T> beanClass) {
    List<T> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    BeanListProcessor<T> processor = new BeanListProcessor<T>(beanClass);
    ...
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: bean.getClass() throws error.. but just passing bean works.

Comment: Ah right, it expects the class of the bean `beanClass` - sorry for that!